# Use batch script to check if file is hidden

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I'm writing a batch file that will unhide and run another batch file or, if the file is already unhidden, will run the batch file and hide it again. How do I check if a file is hidden?

Comment: I have a code which can unhide files when the hidden files can't be unchecked. Here it is - attrib -s -h K:\*.* /s /d But I don't know any method to check how to get a list of hidden files. [Learn More](http://www.markspcsolution.com/2012/10/hidden-option-cant-be-unchecked-fix-it.html)

Comment: Found this on another site.  Same subject.

[windows-batch-script-to-unhide-files-hidden-by-virus][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095002/windows-batch-script-to-unhide-files-hidden-by-virus

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in PowerShell to get a list of hidden files

```
Get-ChildItem X:\My\Path -Recurse -Force | Where { ($_.Attributes.ToString() -Split ", ") -Contains "Hidden" } | Select FullName
```

You should be able to use `dir/ah` for the same result in cmd in the current path.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways.

**1) DIR /AH**   (probably the simplest method)

Use the DIR command to look for a file with a particular attribute. Returns success if found, error if not.

```
dir /ah file.ext >nul 2>nul && (
  echo file.ext is hidden
) || (
  echo file.ext is NOT hidden
)
```

**2) ATTRIB command**

The attribute codes are in upper case. The code for hidden is `H`, and I believe it is always in the fifth position. Use FINDSTR to look for the code.

```
attrib file.ext | findstr "^....H" >nul && (
  echo file.ext is hidden
) || (
  echo file.ext is NOT hidden
)
```

**3) FOR variable `~a` modifier**

The attribute codes are in lower case, and they are in a different order than the ATTRIB command. The code for hidden is `h` in the fourth position. Use FINDSTR to look for the code.

```
for %%F in (file.ext) do echo %%~aF | findstr "^...h" >nul 2>nul &&
  echo file.ext is hidden
) || (
  echo file.ext is NOT hidden
)
```

or use a substring operation. Don't forget that the substring is 0 indexed.

```
for %%F in (file.ext) do set "attr=%%~aF"
if %attr:~3,1% equ h (
  echo file.ext is hidden
) else (
  echo file.ext is NOT hidden
)
```

**4) Parameter `~a` modifier**

Basically the same as with FOR variable, except now using a script or sub-routine parameter.

```
call :IsHidden file.ext &&
  echo file.ext is hidden
) else (
  echo file.ext is NOT hidden
)
exit /b

:isHidden
echo %~a1 | findstr "^...h" >nul 2>nul
exit /b
```

or

```
call :IsHidden file.ext &&
  echo file.ext is hidden
) else (
  echo file.ext is NOT hidden
)
exit /b

:isHidden
setlocal
set "att=%~a1"
if %att:~3,1% equ h exit /b 0
exit /b 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in this first script:

```
dir /ah file.ext >nul 2>nul && (
  echo file.ext is hidden
) || (
  echo file.ext is NOT hidden
)
```

I used it to check if a folder is hidden, but this script above gives false positive feedback if the folder is not hidden and contains a hidden file or folder (and the same is true if you look for any other attribute). The second script seems to work fine:

```
attrib file.ext | findstr "^....H" >nul && (
  echo file.ext is hidden
) || (
  echo file.ext is NOT hidden
)
```

Edit: If you want to check only folders, then add d to the attributes: /adh, and the first script gonna work for you, but I want to check folders and files simultaneously, so for me only the second script is good.

Edit 2: I've corrected the first script:

```
if exist "PATH"\* (
set "attrD="
) else (
set "attrD=-"
)
dir /a:%attrD%dh "PATH" >nul 2>nul && (
  echo %1 is hidden
) || (
  echo %1 is NOT hidden
)
```

This script will show folders as NOT hidden if they are not hidden and contain a hidden file or folder. You have to specify attribute d and it has to be after %attrD%, the position of the other attributes does not matter.